# how to handle "Additional information: The source contains no DataRows."

Tags: asp.net, exception, datatable

I am working on a ASP.Net application and I have a table as follows,

```
   DataTable dtDimnsn = (DataTable)ViewState["dtAccntDimesnDetls"];

   DataTable results = dtDimnsn.Select("AccountNo = 0001").CopyToDataTable();
```

For some situation, there will not be any row with AccountNo = 0001.
At that time it throws an error:

> Additional information: The source contains no DataRows.

How can I handle this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `Linq` and check it there are any rows before calling `CopyToDataTable`.

```
var rows = dtDimnsn.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row["AccountNo"].ToString() == "0001");
DataTable results = rows.Any() ? rows.CopyToDataTable() : dtDimnsn.Clone();
```